# Python - Selenium :Try loop - if and elif not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

New to Python and I am stumped on where I am going wrong here.... Would appreciate some direction. Maybe I'm not even using the correct syntax.

Scenario - if element: looking for button on website to click & the elif element: logs back into the website to continue when prompted for session time out

Objective... Execute Upper code > Run through Try Loop > Execute Lower code

In the below code only the if line code element triggers but never the elif

```
while True:
    try:
        driver.get('http://www.website.com')
        time.sleep(7)
        if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Dogs']"):
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/section/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[6]/div/button').click()
            break
        elif driver.find_element_by_id('labeled-input-animals'):
            activity = driver.find_element_by_id('labeled-input-animals')
            activity.send_keys("Husky")
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[3]/button').click()
            time.sleep(3)
            break
    except:
        print("Searching")
```

Comment: it'd be helpful if you can post the error message. Also, I'm not sure if the indentation is properly reflected here, your try except is not in the while loop

Comment: there's no errors that come up when this is run, currently 1 of two things happen the exception line prints when the if element is not found or the if element is found runs through that code then the outside code below not shown in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation is not proper. The statements below the `while` loop are not "inside" the loop. Refer [here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) for help regarding Python indentation.

Try:

```
while True:
    try:
        driver.get('http://www.website.com')
        time.sleep(7)
        if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Dogs']"): 
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/section/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[6]/div/button').click()
            break
        elif driver.find_element_by_id('labeled-input-animals'):
            activity = driver.find_element_by_id('labeled-input-animals')
            activity.send_keys("Husky")
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[3]/button').click()
            time.sleep(3)
            break
    except:
        print("Searching")
```